How to disable autocomplete suggestions when using the backspace or delete keys in Visual Studio Code?
When using Visual Studio Code, I find the autocomplete suggestions helpful most of the time; however, it's annoying when they appear while I'm deleting text using the backspace or delete keys.
Is there a way to configure Visual Studio Code to disable autocomplete suggestions, specifically while tapping the backspace key?
I've tried adjusting Intellisense, but most attempts just turn off autocomplete suggestions altogether, which is not my intent.

does this happen for you in all language modes? or only a specific one?

It occurs in all the languages that I've used.

do you have quick suggestions enabled? check the editor.quickSuggestions setting

I do have editor.quickSuggestions on for other, which is helpful just when typing normally, but when using backspace or delete it's not useful.

what if you turn quick suggestions off? does that stop it? just curious.

I tried that as well, it didn't work.
